# PostGIS slow performances on small table and basic SELECT query

Tags: postgis, performance

A few weeks ago, I received a query to install a PostGIS database for a few of my users. I'm not familiar with this but yet installed quite simply the extension using the `sudo apt install postgresql-14-postgis-3` command line on my Ubuntu Server.

Everything worked fine, and users started uploading data such as [Swiss Boundaries](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/landscape-model-swissboundaries3d#swissBOUNDARIES3D---Download) data, which contains a quite small table `swissboundaries3d_canton` (~50 rows) to use it in QGIS. They immediately started complaining the database is really slow to query. At first, I thought it would be an issue with missing indexes, but they told me they had a plain simple `SELECT` query on the table takes up to 27 seconds to execute. That seems quite a lot to me! An `EXPLAIN` query did not showcase the issue, but as I understood from reading the [official performance tips of PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/performance_tips.html), that is not surprising:

```sql
gisdb=# explain analyze select * from swissboundaries3d_canton;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on swissboundaries3d_canton  (cost=0.00..10.50 rows=50 width=1396) (actual time=0.204..0.590 rows=50 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 2.625 ms
 Execution Time: 0.609 ms
(3 rows)
```

Is there anything I could do to make it faster to query such table, as an index probably isn't going to do any good?

**Note:** I stumbled upon the "[Why is working with big shapes slow?](https://postgis.net/documentation/faq/big-objects-performance/)" FAQ article from PostGIS but I don't quite understand what shenanigans I have to perform there. If you can't tell, I'm not quite used to GIS data at all, that's new to me.

On the configuration side, let's say the server doesn't seem to be in any difficulty when performing those operations. My config is the following:

- PostgreSQL 14
- PostGIS 3.3.3
- 1 GB RAM and 3.2 GHz of a virtual processor

Comment: Well since your users are asking for the whole table an index will not help as you suspect. To me 1gb of RAM sounds on the small side for spatial data, how detailed are your boundaries, may you can simplify them for when the whole country is being requested

Comment: I feel like 1GB of RAM is the chokepoint , boundaries of canton would be very detailled big polygon ... and so your server have a hard time with it. you can try to run a simplify on this borders to make them a bit lighter (you lose points and therefore have less accurate border but well). Or add some RAM to the server

Comment: 1GiB RAM is between 7 and 23GiB short of make-weight for a database node. I haven't  used less than 16GiB since I retired that 486 box sometime after 9/11.

Comment: Subdividing complex lines/polygons may really help, see this [article](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/11/subdivide.html)

Comment: @Vince lol, now that's *already* been a Frankenstein 20 years ago...

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you for your feedback. I did some monitoring on the server and apparently it never goes beyond 1Gb of RAM, even when I increase the total RAM available to 8 Gb as suggested. I suspect there is something else going on.

Comment: @JGH Thanks for the suggestion, I will check if this is something we can do.